# Realmでデータベースから値を取ろうとすると「EXC_BAD_ACCESS」のエラーが表示される

Tags: swift, ios, realm

現在Realmを使ってデータベースから値を取得しようとしているのですが、「EXC_BAD_ACCESS」エラーが出て取得できません。「EXC_BAD_ACCESS」は以下のコードのreturn文で表示されています。

```
public func objects<T: Object>(_ type: T.Type) -> Results<T> {
    return Results<T>(RLMGetObjects(rlmRealm, (type as Object.Type).className(), nil))
}
```

エラーに関わる範囲のコードを下記に記載します。

```
// MARK: - IBAction

@IBAction func addNewUser(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    self.showAddNewUserAlert()
}

// MARK: - alertController

func showAddNewUserAlert() {
    let alert:UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title:"登録", message: "名前を入力してね", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
    okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler:{ (action:UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
        let textField = alert.textFields![0]

        if self.checkHasSameUserNameInDatabase(textField.text!) {    //エラーが出るメソッド
            let user = User()
            user.name = textField.text!
            UserManager.sharedManager.insertUser(user)
            UserManager.sharedManager.users.append(user)

            let indexPath = IndexPath(row: UserManager.sharedManager.users.count - 1, section: 0)
            self.tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.automatic)
        } else {
            self.showFailureAlert()
        }
    })

    let cancelAction:UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "キャンセル",
        style: UIAlertActionStyle.cancel, handler:{
            (action:UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
    })
    okAction.isEnabled = false
    alert.addAction(cancelAction)
    alert.addAction(okAction)

    alert.addTextField(configurationHandler: {(text:UITextField!) -> Void in
        text.placeholder = "名前"
        text.delegate = self
    })
    present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func checkHasSameUserNameInDatabase(_ name: String!) -> Bool {
    let realm = try! Realm()
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name = %@", name) 
    let users = realm.objects(User.self).filter(predicate)    //ここでエラーが出る

    if users.count == 0 {
        return false
    } else {
        return true
    }
}
```

ちなみにモデルクラスは以下のようになっています。

```
class User: Object {

    dynamic var id = UUID().uuidString
    dynamic var name: String!
    dynamic var score = 0
    dynamic var characterName = "赤ちゃん"

    override class func primaryKey() -> String {
        return "id"
    }

}
```

なぜ値を取得できないのでしょうか？ 
個人的にはバージョンに何か問題があるような気がしているのですが......。 
Swiftのバージョンは3.0で、Realmのバージョンは2.0.0で、iOSのバージョンは10.0.1です。 
どなたかわかる方がいれば教えていただきたいです。よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 他のクエリやそのメソッド以外のところで実行した場合はうまくいくのですか？それともどんなクエリでも同じようにエラーになりますか？問題の切り分けのために`viewDidLoad()`あたりで`let realm = try! Realm()[改行] print(realm.objects(User.self))`として結果が正しく返ってくるかどうか確かめてみてもらえますか？

Comment: viewDidLoad()にlet realm = try! Realm()
        print(realm.objects(User.self))を書いたのですが、「EXC_BAD_ACCESS」エラーが表示されました。ちなみにreturn Results<T>(RLMGetObjects(rlmRealm, (type as Object.Type).className(), nil))文には飛ばなかったです。

Comment: エラーが起こるプロジェクトを共有してもらえませんか？もし公開できないものでしたら、`help@realm.io`にメールしてください。そうすれば私の方で確認することができます。

Comment: はい、プロジェクトは以下になります。お手数をおかけしますが、よろしくお願いします。
https://github.com/tarofess/homework

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/49898

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realmの問題なのかSwiftの問題なのかわかりませんが、プロジェクト名に漢字やカタカナが含まれていることが問題のようです。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

上のスクリーンショットのようにXcodeの機能でプロジェクト名をリネームできますので（関連して必要な変更を自動的にしてくれる）、プロジェクト名をアルファベットのみにするなど変更して使ってください。

Realmの問題かどうかはこれから深く調査します。教えていただいてありがとうございました。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。プロジェクト名の表記が関係していたのですね。では一旦プロジェクト名をリネームしようと思います。ありがとうございました。